# why mutating method applied on instance doesn't save changes? swift

Tags: swift, methods, extension-methods, mutating-function

I extend my custom protocol with mutable function. And then apply it on the instance of the corresponding type. But instance is changed only on that row. On the next row, it has previous value. Why changes made on the instance doesn't persist?

If I assign the result of `mutating` to the `var`/`let`. Then the result saves. Or if I apply `harderWorkout()` in the `print()` statement it print changed value.

```
struct Workout {
    var distance: Double
    var time: Double
    var averageHR: Int
}

extension Workout: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return "Workout(distance: \(distance), time: \(time), averageHR: \(averageHR)"
    }
}

extension Workout {

    mutating func harderWorkout() -> Workout {
    return Workout(distance: (self.distance * 2), time: (self.time * 2), averageHR: (self.averageHR + 40))

    }
}

var workout = Workout(distance: 500, time: 50, averageHR: 100)
print(workout) //Workout(distance: 500.0, time: 50.0, averageHR: 100, Speed: 10.0
workout.harderWorkout()
print(workout) //Workout(distance: 500.0, time: 50.0, averageHR: 100, Speed: 10.0
```

In the last print I expected to see `Workout(distance: 1000.0, time: 100.0, averageHR: 140` but **it's not clear to me why `harderWorkout()` method doesn't change the `workout` instance.** Maybe it's because of the value type. But I put the mutable prefix... 
*Will be very thankful if someone explains to me the reason and its mechanism.*

Comment: because you are not actually `mutating` anything in your implementation – you merely create a new instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of returning `Workout` instance from `harderWorkout()` method, assign the new `Workout` instance to `self`, i.e.

```
extension Workout {
    mutating func harderWorkout() {
        self = Workout(distance: (self.distance * 2), time: (self.time * 2), averageHR: (self.averageHR + 40))
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can simply change the `distance`, `time` and `averageHR` values of the same instance, i.e.

```
extension Workout {
    mutating func harderWorkout() {
        self.distance *= 2
        self.time *= 2
        self.averageHR += 40
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by you want to delete it?

Comment: It works because, simply return the instance doesn't change self. You need to modify self in order to reflect the changes?

Comment: @PGDev "Second one is a better approach since it doesn't create an extra Workout instance." Nope, the first approach is better. 1) Because it calls your initializer, which gives a central location for all initialization logic, rather than fragmenting among unrelated parts of your code, and 2) because the assignment to a `Workout` to `self` (which is already a `Workout`) just causes an in-place construction.

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty, simple - in your `workoutHarder()` you create a new `Workout` and return that, instead of mutating it.

If you expect it to mutate, you will need to to the following:

```
extension Workout {
  mutating func harderWorkout() -> Workout {
    self.distance *= 2
    self.time *=2
    self.averageHR += 40
    return self
  }
}
```

You see that it now returns from `self`, and maybe the method dont need to return at all if you just want it to mutate?

Comment: What's the need to return self explicitly?

Comment: Thanks! It works now without returning the self and with it.

Comment: Since his method signature has a return statement, it needs to return something. I also comment on that at the end, that it properly dont need a return.